# Google app script trigger not writing data to other sheets in same spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following app script associated with a Google Spreadsheet that is accepting data from a Google Form:

```
function writePatientData() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<spreadsheet id>");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);

  //get last row in active/main sheet
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();

  //get last row of data
  var last_row = sheet.getSheetValues(numRows, 1, 1, 23);

  //get patientID (column V) in last row of sheet
  var lastPatientID = sheet.getRange(numRows,3).getValue();

  //find patient sheet based on patientID and make it active, then write to it
  var patientSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(lastPatientID);
  var activePatientSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(lastPatientID);
  activePatientSheet.getRange(activePatientSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1,1,23).setValues(last_row);
}
```

What this script is doing is writing data (a row) to another sheet within this spreadsheet based on the the patientID (column V). This works as it should when I manually run the script. However, when I set a trigger to run this script (either onSubmit or edit) nothing happens. I created another function that just writes a message to the logs and set a trigger for that function and it works, so I think there is something in the script that is causing it to fail. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: What errors do you see in Stackdriver logs?

Comment: can you share your spreadsheet please?

Comment: tehhowch I am not using stackdriver (I guess maybe I should be) @JSmith, added a link to the spreadsheet

Comment: Stackdriver will log errors that occur during the execution. Triggered functions (installable or simple) do not display errors in the UI - they can only log exceptions elsewhere (i.e. to Stackdriver).

Comment: Is there an active sheet when you openById()? The active sheet is the one that is being displayed but none are being displayed.  There is no display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. I tried to fix it while commenting each line I changed. Hopefully that is clear enough, please comment if you have any questions and I'll try to clarify.

```
function writePatientData() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); //no need for id if the script is on the same spreadsheet
  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
  //setActiveSheet will not work from a trigger like on-form-submit (what if no-one has the sheet open, or multiple have)
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]; //if you want the first sheet, just get it, no need to "activate"

  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();

  var last_row = sheet.getSheetValues(numRows, 1, 1, 23)[0]; //added [0] since it is just one row

  //var lastPatientID = sheet.getRange(numRows,3).getValue(); //you already have this in memory
  var lastPatientID = last_row[2]; //arrays are zero based, that's why 2 instead of 3
  //btw, you mention column V, but this is actually C

  //var patientSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(lastPatientID);
  //you already have the spreadsheet, no need to get it again
  var patientSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(lastPatientID);
  //var activePatientSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(lastPatientID); //this is the exact same as above, why?
  patientSheet.appendRow(last_row); //appendRow is just simpler than getRange(getLastRow).setValues
}
```

Comment: Boom! You da man Henrique. Love it works right out of the box. Looks like setActiveSheet was the reason the trigger was not working, but appreciate the edits with comments.